# How can I know if my Android Tablet supports Wi-Fi N?

Tags: wi-fi

How can I know if my Android Tablet supports Wi-Fi N and speed up to 150 MBps?
I don't have any description covering that in device specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try switching your router temporarily to 802.11n-only mode and see if the tablet still connects. If the tablet doesn't connect, it doesn't support it.

Comment: Unfortunately the BT Home Hub 3 "n-only mode" (802.11 n 40 MHz) still allows legacy 802.11g devices to connect, despite a warning to the contrary... "802.11 b/g devices are not compatible."